# Mass signature of PDF's in Web Server PHP+Html+JavaScript, with USB Token

Tags: web, server, digital, signer

I have a web application developed by me, in PHP, to sign PDFs, for which the user imports the digital certificate to the server during the validity period of the certificate, the user can sign several PDFs, the usual thing is that he signs 1 per month , now I have the case of use that requires the simultaneous signing of, for example, hundreds or thousands of pdfs, this user who must sign these PDFs does not import the certificate to the application, they must sign them with a USB Token connected to their computer, to In this case, a few years ago I developed an application in nodejs + electron, which connected from the web applications via socket, downloaded all the PDFs, then signed them with the usb token, and later uploaded them to the server. The problem with this is how slow the process can be, and not to mention the interruptions that can arise from Internet connections.
What alternatives do I have to sign the PDF batches that can be, as I mentioned, hundreds or thousands of pdfs, what alternative do I have to read the usb token, transfer the certificate and the key or pin, and sign the PDFs on the server, Which is where the pdfs are created through a process with the TCPDF library? Is there any way to do this?
Alcaro, I don't have much experience in digital certificates and digital signatures, just basic knowledge.

I would appreciate it very much if you could help me.

To date, they are downloaded, then signed, and finally uploaded to the web server. I have not found an alternative, to sign with a usb token but on the server.